# How to create an Android file list with working back-button?

Tags: java, android

I've used this file list for my new Android app:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

But the problem is that after I've browsed through the folders and then pressing the back-button of my phone, the app is closing instead of going to the previous folder.

(because it's still on the same activity, only some variables are changed)

Is there a possibility to fix this file browser that I can use the back-button without creating multiple activities?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in your activity and do whatever you need there to go to a previous directory.

Comment: Is there any "addToBacktrace()" like call for this?